# Chapel LinearAlgebra reports an error on a call to eig( csrA, left = true, right = true );

Tags: chapel

Using the **[chapel](/questions/tagged/chapel)** [**`code`** inside online IDE](https://tio.run/##zVbfb9s2EH7XX3FoV8Tu9KOyk6yQ6wyC6yEBEruw071kwUBTZ5sYJXkkndj74@ceKSlxkmHG1pfwxeSZ5H333d1H8SVbodzt1hrhUhTIVCoXOFMsnK6Y0ujDxTj8pVQ5Mwazi3HP83hZzMUC7piCEfSh24NDI4rgim3B@igLMEuEweVFwPNMkkcoFSxRkacZyvIeRLVDsnXByX6kIVWLdY6F0SHLsgSCYNT/xEbrfIbqzPMsDq7V5/FVejECAjSYTj6XORNFC0Y@QWz3XsIZKGQGgRWA@cpsobvp2nOQuYPkoh5nsDRmpZMo4o6oQLJiEZZqEWUl19FKiRyVjrTjKlyaXL6tbUFla@BdMaPEJq3gVYvWI2wfeJmvJG4s2D14DlPudkN5h4qYEboG6cF/HnTzNVHLZnQX0EX451rcMUnUgimTZ5stcHKdJnDzgPMWPmVmu8IzWwYPnP/Yh1bsx@3eYfdplgHTjvcN5oxCtsmmuhBFJjhqwuGyX5HXpGNOJcKkdP8UZfEXqhIyZljAUUr9Akmn3Xtm6/yjLX5h6/rddhVana9QIaUM4rDz72VOoU3RPITGbDId5AYuSnQl7DtrFZ7cQiY0@ZmtqbeqBLMmZkuIQm7sJtScNtGW2Xa/ZogrRmmSa@qhucO4j1zkhDw4Dk9OXzlyh1F43r0SBucteENFH1TqA1UwkCbJzTsBG3gnbmFJWN1ZTYeT34o3/mMrjPbnj1ObVHe9LFr73dg@RE1q26QgVWJOIuqyrDrS86L30WscnlWQSTo9DybDL@PJdVKJZMsFhWKBxa/p5dehbriSODdDZx4OrseTxq7EYvnEDm2qKDq/T6HvTpPdqDVJuDtTr2otC56PA5qal9laImkr43@wBU2ePktOY5@aCBLlInq1ubgW43DydZQkdhHyMsPQiDLky5VMOp0EUKlSJbAuFOpS3lG3cNtqR5bqm8GUHjMSK1GY1ulx26@abM8wZ1Jj23f8u3ltuW3elFbc@diu8tSP6xT14/aRRfPD4PzL5e/n46vhId4d2vj4w3FC/WAwqZ4izqjZM/tW0Y/9w/YGXyauTOzTcQs/Gx@obVjeVEoFsrY1BVNh/k5IM@TMfmTc2@8J4NIt0GoFszJFquPc/B8vp/HHxstDzCSZCr8j1D1N2utKK1YA7yNvt9vZT5345CSOfzrpfPibzyVbaDLOmTbfAA) for prototyping, an [*example2.chpl*](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/modules/packages/LinearAlgebra.html#compiling-with-linear-algebra) from [Documentation](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/modules/packages/LinearAlgebra.html#compiling-with-linear-algebra) about how to use the `LinearAlgebra` module ***`proc`* `eig(…)`** failed to operate on CSR-sparse matrix of complex values, **`csrMatrixA`**-instance.

[*Code:*](https://tio.run/##zVbfb9s2EH7XX3FoV8Tu9KOyk6yQ6wyC6yEBEruw071kwUBTZ5sYJXkkndj74@ceKSlxkmHG1pfwxeSZ5H333d1H8SVbodzt1hrhUhTIVCoXOFMsnK6Y0ujDxTj8pVQ5Mwazi3HP83hZzMUC7piCEfSh24NDI4rgim3B@igLMEuEweVFwPNMkkcoFSxRkacZyvIeRLVDsnXByX6kIVWLdY6F0SHLsgSCYNT/xEbrfIbqzPMsDq7V5/FVejECAjSYTj6XORNFC0Y@QWz3XsIZKGQGgRWA@cpsobvp2nOQuYPkoh5nsDRmpZMo4o6oQLJiEZZqEWUl19FKiRyVjrTjKlyaXL6tbUFla@BdMaPEJq3gVYvWI2wfeJmvJG4s2D14DlPudkN5h4qYEboG6cF/HnTzNVHLZnQX0EX451rcMUnUgimTZ5stcHKdJnDzgPMWPmVmu8IzWwYPnP/Yh1bsx@3eYfdplgHTjvcN5oxCtsmmuhBFJjhqwuGyX5HXpGNOJcKkdP8UZfEXqhIyZljAUUr9Akmn3Xtm6/yjLX5h6/rddhVana9QIaUM4rDz72VOoU3RPITGbDId5AYuSnQl7DtrFZ7cQiY0@ZmtqbeqBLMmZkuIQm7sJtScNtGW2Xa/ZogrRmmSa@qhucO4j1zkhDw4Dk9OXzlyh1F43r0SBucteENFH1TqA1UwkCbJzTsBG3gnbmFJWN1ZTYeT34o3/mMrjPbnj1ObVHe9LFr73dg@RE1q26QgVWJOIuqyrDrS86L30WscnlWQSTo9DybDL@PJdVKJZMsFhWKBxa/p5dehbriSODdDZx4OrseTxq7EYvnEDm2qKDq/T6HvTpPdqDVJuDtTr2otC56PA5qal9laImkr43@wBU2ePktOY5@aCBLlInq1ubgW43DydZQkdhHyMsPQiDLky5VMOp0EUKlSJbAuFOpS3lG3cNtqR5bqm8GUHjMSK1GY1ulx26@abM8wZ1Jj23f8u3ltuW3elFbc@diu8tSP6xT14/aRRfPD4PzL5e/n46vhId4d2vj4w3FC/WAwqZ4izqjZM/tW0Y/9w/YGXyauTOzTcQs/Gx@obVjeVEoFsrY1BVNh/k5IM@TMfmTc2@8J4NIt0GoFszJFquPc/B8vp/HHxstDzCSZCr8j1D1N2utKK1YA7yNvt9vZT5345CSOfzrpfPibzyVbaDLOmTbfAA)

```
use LinearAlgebra.Sparse, IO.FormattedIO;

config var N = 3;                                 // May use on the CLI-cmdline or here, below in the launcher's Arguments.add: --N=<aNumber>

var csrDOMAIN  = CSRDomain( N, N );               // Create an empty 3x3 CSR domain ---------> https://chapel-lang.org/docs/primers/sparse.html#primers-sparse
var csrMatrixA = CSRMatrix( csrDOMAIN, complex ); // Create a CSR matrix over this domain
                                                  // The above is equivalent to:               var matA: [csrDOMAIN] <dtype>;

csrDOMAIN += (1,1);                               // Add as an exemaple these indices to the sparse domain for all the nonzero data-cells
csrDOMAIN += (1,2);
csrDOMAIN += (2,2);
csrDOMAIN += (2,1);
csrDOMAIN += (3,3);

csrMatrixA.re =  1.23;                            // Set as an example all nonzero elements, all sparsely distributed over a domain indirectly described by csrDOMAIN, to a value of 1.23
csrMatrixA.im = -4.56;                            // Set as an example all nonzero elements, all sparsely distributed over a domain indirectly described by csrDOMAIN, to a value of-4.56i

writef( "CSR-Sparse Matrix A::[%i x %i] has values of:\n",
         N,
         N
         );

writeln( csrMatrixA );                            // A is now a 3x3 sparse matrix

/*/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CRASH-REPORT:

var (     eigenVALUEs,
     rightEigenVECTORs ) = eig( csrMatrixA, right = true ); // ------------------------------> https://chapel-lang.org/docs/modules/packages/LinearAlgebra.html#LinearAlgebra.eig

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// TiO.RUN::
// .code.tio.chpl:22: error: unresolved call 'eig([CSDom(2,int(64),domain(2,int(64),false),true,false,false)] complex(128), left=1, right=1)'
// $CHPL_HOME/modules/packages/LinearAlgebra.chpl:1404: note: this candidate did not match: eig(A: [] ?t, param left = false, param right = false)
// $CHPL_HOME/modules/packages/LinearAlgebra.chpl:1404: note: because where clause evaluated to false
// $CHPL_HOME/modules/packages/LinearAlgebra.chpl:1618: note: candidates are: eig(A: [] ?t, param left = false, param right = false)
//

writeln( eigenVALUEs );
  */
```

*Compiler settings:* **`--fast`**
*Runtime parameters:* `--N=3` (not relevant atm)

**Could you kindly advice**:
***a)*** what would be the proper way to meet the expected syntax ( call-signature )
 and 
***b)*** could you kindly extend the repaired MCVE-code example one step further, so as to demonstrate how to make the `eig()`-processing to actually operate in a parallel-distributed fashion on a very sparse, non-sym. CSR-domain `N x N` for `N ~ 2E7` ( having `~ 5 [GB]` of actual data ), distributed not because of RAM-sizing, but for the faster processing, over multiple locale, so as to efficiently harness all the CPU-resources available
and
***c)*** what would be a net **[chapel](/questions/tagged/chapel)** processing speedup of such an approach, if benchmarked against a colocated, single locale processing?

*Traceback:*

> `$CHPL_HOME/modules/packages/LinearAlgebra.chpl:1404: note:`
> `this candidate did not match: eig(A: [] ?t, param left = false, param right = false)`
>   `$CHPL_HOME/modules/packages/LinearAlgebra.chpl:1404: note:`
> `because where clause evaluated to false`
>   `$CHPL_HOME/modules/packages/LinearAlgebra.chpl:1618: note:`
> `candidates are: eig(A: [] ?t, param left = false, param right = false)`

---

Recent re-tests, after Ben Albrecht's *[[issue-14725]](https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/issues/14725)* ticket was filed, confirm both `(complex)` and `(int)` *eltType*-s crash in a similar manner, yet a `(real)` `CSRMatrix()`-instance throws a LAPACK-code error: as documented in [updated-**code**](https://tio.run/##1Vhtb@JGEP7OrxhdezpI/XKGvJ25pLIIp6ASiAhXVUqj02IPYHX90t0lCf3xTWfXNiFJ1ZBGUel@yXrY9Tw788wz64RzliO/u1tIhH6cIhMBn@FEMOciZ0KiBb2h8yUTCVMKo96wXauFWTqNZ3DNBAzgCFpteG64LpyxJWgfWQpqjtDp9@wwiTh5hEzAHAV5miDPbiAuVnC2SEOyf5AQiNkiwVRJh0WRD7Y9OPrMBotkguK4VtM4QilOhmdBbwAEqHMxOskSFqd1GFgEsdF@CqcjkCkElgImuVpC67al90FkNpKLchzDXKlc@q4bmkDZnKUzJxMzN8pC6eYiTlBIV5pYOXOV8O9Km13YKFwrbD8cQd2zvEb7@XAFUQRMGny3mLCcow4KxS9OozhECSozUSqcVLCnFErGufklzdI/UGQQMcXsEDmXT5A0G@1Htubf2rwntpbVIlvN3YFNct8bjH34EvT63RMfwnnO/d0DH1CITPiwSAXKjF9jBKHG/gHjWf2yc0EpJNdxqur7uw2rOOCaYcq4xIalxAKLeWm5gmoFcJyqI88CEc/mNGl8qKhyxpSIb4OCKsVD/Z5Cln5DRZo1qujFdmJWQzbVi2wJ2TUKCncsyxTU4MWDXIwpX2xC7wJ6Ef6@iK8ZJ75Tkv1Hi/UJCEPgw@UK8BV8jtQyx2OTpepwoEvB9jbg2gWqFddYoqmm81DxBzma2rOMteAbX0IUS/IzWZAoFEFgFQk1QwWGSi9CGdIiWjJZrgeYyMvoKHxBxT@1vVrtRsQKp3V4p2NcCA8UB4HA9y/fx3AL7@MrqFPUGzAntGY3xX/q/5q@s@7DPlif30@JrRslY8etUUQ2ydmoG/TvWf195/S8/@10eNZ1kyxacCRtYOFvbEaTfnAedH5yDPG9TwcHeyvuh99yJcYZ1YBc5HkmdDCZECSVOp@b0pX4yUu@PqIrVHTdbpbCgXP4qb3dLDUYX0BUnZQ3Zarrbiq/neHZeb/7yyMJbjbfToLDTCfotu41D1@jw@VrNLf/b8R2BGpie06zte3E1hjXkceJbhy7zt7@liM3GOMX1GTJp@1oIAVsntbXK6HxXMgDTdGUbsnMXFnL619RDXQf286hI9IZBRen9qh7PhzRZVBfVFfp0B0sp9qWhdm0eORqTDVlwZI4ZsyFoJrXwAxpMW0qO6Z8m/ZrZKpuIk@CiOnPQf9rV1b00KrWNeZuZzwcVXYjcut2aFA5aUFdy3OhiWQ32lnsKZ9KsbMfj2c@RJ6e@sG3nPkweWgiSFtNmHE8dEZfB76vH5wwi9BRceb8572L0Pwj2x4EuSDd7sddn4pWoV/0qpCR0kW6mdEf/YMu4HDuG5ro3nIFPyoLqLZZUjGlAFnaKsIUmF8JaYIh01/mN/ojHEJuHlDLI9MFQZJr3PwbL/veYeVldWbqFwJfcdTavXCuVaXWZ30d2nHv7u70Pwi8vT3PO9hrfvwznHI2k2ScMqn@Ag)

> `$CHPL_HOME/modules/packages/LAPACK.chpl:19775: error:`
>  `c_ptrTo unsupported array type`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) It looks like this is an unimplemented feature for the linear algebra library. I have filed an issue here: https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/issues/14725

b) Chapel 1.20 does not yet have a distributed eigen solver in the `LinearAlgebra` module. I encourage you to open an issue on the github repository requesting this feature if you would find it valuable.

c) See (b)

Comment: If I read the text of the filed *[issue-14725]* ticket, does it mean that for any of other *{ int | real }* eltType-s ( i.e. other than the ***complex*** one ) the Chapel code shall compile and run smooth - both the *CSRMatrix()*-instantiation and the call to *LinearAlgebra.Sparse.eig( )* - or does it mean the problem is not with the eltType per-se ( the *complex* fails as do *real* and *int* ) as the problem is in not handling the sparse-representation properly? **Test for CSR (real)** confirms the latter? $CHPL_HOME/modules/packages/LAPACK.chpl:19775: error: c_ptrTo unsupported array type?

Comment: There's actually 2 issues: `eig()` does not yet support complex types (#14725 ), and `eig()` does not support sparse matrices (no issue for this yet) -- would you be interested in filing a feature request?

Comment: The c) is the most important argument for Chapel to demonstrate the benefits of economy in using productive parallel language,as Chapel has always strived to be.If filing tickets might help,feel free to do whatever needed.Yet,the core business logic is not in ticketing,but in delivering benefits with business sense.Having a sparse module but without having also all the LinearAlgebra methods covered is blocking the main purpose of having them,isn't it? If I were to demonstrate the powers of a productivity-focused language to public,then it would be on productivity benefits, not on issue-tickets

Comment: I fully understand the complexity of current business realms, the more the impacts on company-sponsored public domain software, so my fingers are crossed and wishing Brad & all the Team all the best for managing both the forthcoming language releases and the primary visions, that have started the so cute productive parallel programming language the Chapel foundations out of questions are and hopefully will be, all for the good of the growing bases of the scientific computing use,where **End-to-End productivity**, incl.the coding, **matters** (often more than an as-is method's performance test)

Comment: Yes, a complete dense/sparse distributed GPU-supported linear algebra library is my vision for Chapel, but there are only so many resources available and many competing priorities, so it will take some time.

Following up on this issue, #14725 has been resolved on master (1.21.0 pre-release).